# How do I recieve DAO tokens? What's the address?

Tags: ether, the-dao, exchanges, dao

I'm trying to buy some DAO tokens via shapeshift and it asks a DAO address to send the tokens to. Where do I find that address? Is it the same as my Ether wallet address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the answer to this is yes, an Ethereum address is the same as a DAO address. I just did a small test with [ShapeShift.io](http://shapeshift.io/) converting to DAO tokens. In the field being sent to I placed my Ethereum address. I configured Mist using [these instructions](https://forum.daohub.org/t/how-do-i-see-my-dao-tokens-in-ethereum-wallet-mist/580) and I now see my DAO token balance. It also gives me the option to send DAO tokens from that Ethereum address.

Interestingly it still shows my balance as 0 DAO on [daohub.org](https://daohub.org/index.html). Hopefully it's just a bit lagged behind.

20160717 Update: My DAO token balance is now reflected properly on [daohub.org](https://daohub.org/index.html).